# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"eventGroups"' can't be used to index type 'MonthViewDay<EventGroupMeta>'

Tags: angular, angular-calendar

I'm following the tutorial for Angular 14+ calendar here:
https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/group-similar-events

But it's giving me an exception when trying to assign the array.

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"eventGroups"' can't be used to index type 'MonthViewDay<EventGroupMeta>'.
  Property 'eventGroups' does not exist on type 'MonthViewDay<EventGroupMeta>'.ts(7053)
```

What am I missing here?

```
beforeMonthViewRender({
        body,
      }: {
        body: CalendarMonthViewDay<EventGroupMeta>[];
      }): void {
        // month view has a different UX from the week and day view so we only really need to group by the type
        body.forEach((cell) => {
          var groups: any;
          cell.events.forEach((event: CalendarEvent<EventGroupMeta>) => {
            groups[event.meta!.type] = groups[event.meta!.type] || [];
            groups[event.meta!.type].push(event);
          });
          cell['eventGroups'] = Object.entries(groups);
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to dig into the types used in the github packages, I was able to trace it to [this file](https://github.com/mattlewis92/calendar-utils/blob/main/src/calendar-utils.ts) but I am under the impression that the error needs to be removed, so you can use the type `{[key: string]: any}` which will accept any inputs.

```
beforeMonthViewRender({
    body,
  }: {
    body: CalendarMonthViewDay<EventGroupMeta>[];
  }): void {
    // month view has a different UX from the week and day view so we only really need to group by the type
    body.forEach((cell) => {
      const groups: {[key: string]: any} = {};
      cell.events.forEach((event: CalendarEvent<EventGroupMeta>) => {
        groups[event.meta.type] = groups[event.meta.type] || [];
        groups[event.meta.type].push(event);
      });
      cell['eventGroups'] = Object.entries(groups);
    });
  }
```

Since you did not define type for groups we are getting the error, where angular is asking you to define a type!

Comment: Still getting the same error as before even when defining a type for groups.
Property 'eventGroups' does not exist on type 'MonthViewDay<EventGroupMeta>'

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a permanent fix (which is why I didn't accept my own answer). But as a dirty workaround I added       // @ts-ignore to ignore the error.

Comment: You can also disable `implicit any` error in your tsconfig (or you can also configure it as a warning)